# Add items in GridView upon SelectionChanged of Asp:Calendar

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
     <Columns>
          <asp:DynamicField HeaderText="Test" />
     </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I want to do that when a date is selected from *asp:Calendar* then change the column values of  GridView by this...

```
protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // add/modify values of columns of GridView.
}
```

Comment: you need to create a data-source for your grid and then bind it with grid.

Comment: What have you tried, what was the problem? It's not clear how the columns are related to the calendar or what issue you have at all.

Comment: @TimSchmelter For now, I just want to show whatever the date selected upon click on calendar. 
  GridView2.Columns.Add( Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString());

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add a single value then you can use

```
List<string> dates=new List<string>();
protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   dates.Add(Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString());
   GridView2.DataSource=dates;
   GridView2.DataBind();
}
```

But you might want to add multiple date in your grid then you need to persist the value of your list in `Session` or somewhere for the next Data-Binding.

Comment: System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' does not contain a definition for 'add' and no extension method 'add' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Its `Add` rather than `add` that is typo.